# Get random color inside forEach() in chalk.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chalk

I am running a `forEach()` loop, and I need to `console.log()`. But I want to get a different color for each iteration. I went trhough docs, but couldn't find anything. Is there any way possible to achieve the same?

```
let arr = ["a", "ab, "abc"]
arr.forEach(arr, e => {
  console.log(chalk.red(e)) //maybe something like - chalk.randColor()
})
```

Comment: chalk.rgb() or use the other 16 colors using a switch case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// Create an array of possible colors
const color = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'gray'];
let arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"]
arr.forEach(arr, e => {
  // and get a random color name from the array
  // and call the function on it
  console.log(chalk[color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]](e))
})
```

Comment: You will get an ````Unexpected token```` error in line 7. Remove the dot before ````[color[Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length)]](e))````

Answer (score 1):

You can define an array of strings (all supported colors)

```
const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
```

Then in each iteration get a random color and use `chalk[color]`

```js
let arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"];
const getRandomColor = (str) => {
  const colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
  console.log(chalk[colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]](str));
};

arr.forEach(getRandomColor);
```

Comment: Good, but put the chalk in color function to encapsulate all that concern in one place."getRandomChalk". Leaking that complexity will lead to potential bugs in consumers of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JoshWulf. Moved chalk to the function

Comment: Beautiful. If you lift console.log, you could do: `arr.forEach(LogWithRandomColor)`

Answer (score 0):

These two functions provide much bigger range of different colors randomly:

```js
// Using chalk.hex()
const randColorHex = (msg) => {
  chalk.hex('#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16))(msg);
}

// Using chalk.rgb()
const randColorRgb = (msg) => {
  const rand = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  chalk.rgb(rand(), rand(), rand())(msg);
}

// Usage
let arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"];

arr.forEach(item => console.log(randColorHex(item)));
arr.forEach(item => console.log(randColorRgb(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `chalk.rgb` with randomizer value to give all level of combination colors to you.

```js
let arr = ["a", "ab", "abc"]
const rdClr = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
const randomClor = str => chalk.rgb(rdClr(), rdClr(), rdClr())(str);
arr.forEach(arr, e => {
  console.log(randomClor(arr + '%s'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com), the randomness can be simpler and more readable, like this:

```
var array = ["a", "ab", "abc"], colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'gray'];

array.forEach((item, i) => console.log(chalk[rando(colors).value](i)));
```

If you want to use this code, just make sure this is in the head tag of your html document:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```